# Let $ |G| = pq, (p > q) $, where $ p $ and $ q $ are distinct primes. Show that $ G $ has at most one subgroup of order $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra

As above my question is : Let $ |G| = pq, (p > q) $, where $ p $ and $ q $ are distinct primes. Show that $ G $ has at most one subgroup of order $p$.

Some background info, i have not learnt anything regarding p-sylow yet and i am not sure how to prove it. I am aware that every proper subgroup of $G$ is cyclic due to a simpple consequence of lagrange.

Pls help

Comment: Hint: Show that any subgroup of order $p$ is normal. Then note that if there were two such, then their product would also be a subgroup. But what would the order of this subgroup be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sketch: Suppose (for contradiction) that $H_1$ and $H_2$ are different subgroups of order $p$.  Observe that since $p$ is prime, every non-identity element of $H_1$ and $H_2$ is a generator.  Therefore, $H_1\cap H_2=\{e\}$.  Then, there are $a,b\in G$ such that $H_1=\langle a\rangle$ and $H_2=\langle b\rangle$.  I claim that the set
$$
A=\{a^ib^j:0\leq i,j<p\}
$$
consists of $p^2$ distinct elements of $G$.  If the elements were not distinct, then for some $(i_1,j_1)$ and $(i_2,j_2)$, 
$$
a^{i_1}b^{j_1}=a^{i_2}b^{j_2}
$$
Therefore, $a^{i_1-i_2}=b^{j_2-j_1}$ is in both $H_1$ and $H_2$.  Hence $a^{i_1-i_2}=e$ and $b^{j_2-j_1}=e$ as well.  Therefore, $i_1=i_2$ and $j_2=j_1$.  Since $A$ consists of $p^2>pq$ distinct elements, we have a contradiction.

As @ilovewt mentions below, once we have that $H_1\cap H_2=\{e\}$, we can conclude that $|H_1H_2|=\frac{|H_1||H_2|}{|H_1\cap H_2|}=p^2$, which is not possible.

Comment: Do you mean "non-identity element" and $H_1\cap H_2=\lbrace e \rbrace$?

Comment: @mathmax Yes, thanks.  Apparently, I'm not yet awake this morning.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I cant really understand the part where you claimed $A $ contains all distinct elements of $G$. Are you saying that $A$ = $G$?

Comment: I'm saying that we're writing down the elements $a^ib^j$.  However, it is possible that we've written down the same element more than once (i.e., two choices of $(i,j)$ result in the same element).  The rest of the sketch shows that this cannot happen.

Comment: I'm not saying that $A=G$.  I'm saying that if $H_1$ and $H_2$ were to exist, then it would imply that $A\subseteq G$ exists where $|A|>|G|$, which is impossible.

Comment: @MichaelBurr ok i understood what you said, but i still dont get why $|A| = p^2$, sorry i am kinda slow cause im still learning this module!

Comment: $|A|=p^2$ because there are $p$ possibilities for $i$ ($0\leq i<p$), there are $p$ possibilities for $j$ ($0\leq j<p$), and each $a^ib^j$ is a different element of $G$.

Comment: or rather can i use the fact that since $H_1 \cap H_2 = \{e\}$, and $A = |H_1H_2| = |H_1||H_2| = p^2$? it is a theorem that i learnt that i just tried to apply

Comment: Yes, I essentially proved that theorem in a special case above (it is likely that the proofs are very similar).

Comment: There is a subtlety using that theorem that $|H_1H_2| = |H_1||H_2|/|H_1\cap H_2|$: it needs to be justified that $H_1H_2$ is actually a subgroup of $G$ before we can claim that the order of $H_1H_2$ is $p^2$, violating Lagrange's Theorem.

Comment: @AOrtiz Actually, the theorem holds even when $H_1H_2$ is not a subgroup.  See the [wikipedia link here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_of_group_subsets).  In this case, $|H_1H_2|$ is taken as the set $H_1H_2=\{h_1h_2:h_1\in H_1,h_2\in H_2\}$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, yes the theorem holds when $H_1H_2$ is not a subgroup, but one has to justify that $H_1H_2$ is a subgroup to appeal to Lagrange's Theorem and say that we indeed found a contradiction.

Comment: @AOrtiz The contradiction here isn't using Lagrange's theorem.  It's merely that the subset $H_1H_2$ of $G$ has more elements than $G$ itself.

Answer (score 0):

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ of order $p$, then $G$ acts on the $q$ left cosets of $H$. If $K$ is the kernel of this action then $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $K \leq H$. The group of permutations of the $q$ cosets has order $|G:K|=|G:H||H:K|$. Now $|G:K|$ is a divisor of $q!$ thus so is $q.|H:K|$. This implies that  $|H:K|$ cannot be $p$ so $H = K$ and normal.

Answer (score 0):

Sketch of proof: Suppose that $H_1$ and $H_2$ are different subgroups of order pq. You can consider the inequality:
$$[G:H_1]\geq[H_1\vee{H_2}:H_1]\geq[H_2:H_1\cup{H_2}]$$
which shows that is a contradiction.